# ARM static relocations for elf format

Tags: arm, elf, relocation

Is there some good document explaining step by step how to apply static arm relocations in elf relocatable files?

I've found this http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/IHI0044E_aaelf.pdf but it's still very confusing. I'm not sure  I'm getting segmentation faults over and over again...Please, someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be to study some preexisting linker I would say. Check [Android Bionic's Linker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/linker/linker.cpp) for example. It looks easier to study with around 2000 lines of code.